# What's a good "running" beer?

Tags: beer, session-beer

The question came up when I saw a post on [dailymile](http://dailymile.com) about a [50k HAT beer](http://www.dailymile.com/blog/nutrition/even-more-cowbell-brewing-beer-for-the-hat-50k).  Personally, I find the lower alcohol, lower carbonation (smoother) beers to be very refreshing after a run.  Even cheap commercial beers can be very refreshing after a run (e.g. Coors, PBR) Has anyone dedicated a homebrew recipe specifically towards sports?

Comment: I'm thinking a good 4-loko clone would give me the energy I needed for a long run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a place in Portland (surprise) called Hopworks:
http://www.hopworksbeer.com/

When I was there a few years ago they had a beer for road bikers that was part wheat, part lemonade and I believe a few pinches of salt. I know some people use Wheat beers with Gatorade - but that sounds kind of disgusting to be honest :).

If I had to fashion a recipe off the top of my head...

4lbs 2-row (or 4lbs of extract)
1lb honey malt

1oz Northern Brewer
1oz Tettnanger (40 mins in)
1oz Goldings (last 5)

I'd use an easy on the palette yeast - maybe an ESB.

When you cut to the second stage, slice up some fruit sangria-style: lemons, limes, pineapple (whatever you like) and pop them into mesh bag. Not sure how many - maybe one lemon, one lime, 3 cuts of fresh pineapple.

When the fermentation completes you could add water if the fruit's too strong. I would then add some minerals for hydration and some salt. I think the salt will be the thing that makes it - your body craves it when working out.

If you can do lagers I'd say to replace the above recipe with a nice Czech pilsner. MM

Comment: The heff/lemonade combo sounds like a treat to me, but mixing Gatorade with anything other than water sounds like a gag-reflex inducing concoction.  I think the honey malt is a great idea.  I'm not sure what the effects of salt would be on the fermentation process, so I'd probably experiment with putting the salt in right before bottling or even adding a pinch right before drinking.

Comment: Yeah, they've been making this for almost 100 years in Bavaria for bikers in the Alps, they call it a Radler.  They usually mix it with a lager though, and sometimes they'll use lemon-lime soda instead of lemonade. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radler

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Berliner Weisse?   Light, refreshingly tart, and not enough alcohol to contribute to dehydration in a significant way.